# How can I vectorize this code in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

How can I implement this Matlab code without using a for loop?

```
b=10:10:50
a=50*rand(1,50);

for ii=2:numel(b)
    ind{ii}=find(a<b(ii) & a>b(ii-1));
end
```

Comment: What do you mean, 'vectorize' it? On each step of the loop you are throwing away the previously calculated value of `ind`, so you only need to perform the last step. Is there a mistake in your code?

Comment: By vectorize I mean without the for loop. ind can be a cell for that matter. I'll edit the question so it'll be more clear.

Comment: To do *exactly* what you are doing here (using `find`, storing result in a cell array) a loop may well be your fastest bet. On the other hand, if your program can make use of logical indexing or some other technique, a non-loop solution might speed things up.  You haven't provided enough information to know that, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are doing a histogram and keeping track of which element ends up in which bin. This means you can get "almost" what you want with the following lines:

```
a = 50 * rand(1, 50);
b = 10:10:50;
[h c] = histc(a, b);
```

Now c contains the index of the "bin" of each element in a. For example if

```
a = [15 22 9 7 25];
```

Then

```
c = [1 2 0 0 2];
```

Not sure of the value of collecting these into a cell array - it seems to me whatever you want to do with the values in `ind` can be done with `c`.

I suspect it may be hard to create a cell array (with possibly different lengths) with a "vector" operation (which implies things with the same length)... Would be interested to see someone produce a counterexample!

EDIT: I discovered my own counterexample... the following line produces a cell array `ind` just as your code did (the `arrayfun` command does have an implied `for` loop but is considered "vectorized").

```
ind = arrayfun(@(x)find(x==c),1:numel(b)-1, 'uniformoutput', false);
```

Note when this is done the cell array `ind` has values from cell `ind{1}` onwards, while your original code indexed from cell `ind{2}`. If that is an issue I'm sure you can fix it...

Also note that your code is generating random numbers between `0` and `50`, but your "valid bins" are only between `10` and `50` (because of how you wrote your algorithm). Thus the sum of indices collected will be a bit less than 50 (40, on average).

Comment: thanks, I guess that is the answer, although for relatively small numbers, the for loop is still faster. When you got to bigger arrays the arrayfun wins...

Comment: You are right - but you asked for vectorized code, not for fast code... I learnt something (about arrayfun()) by answering this - so thanks to you too.

Answer (score 2):

The script below will do the same thing. The matrix `newInd` will contain the same values that are assigned to `ind` and printed out by your loop.

```
b=10:10:50;
a=sort(randi(50,1,10));

% create shifted version of vector b to account
% for comparison between i and i-1
newB1 = b(1:end-1);
newB2 = b(2:end);

% create tiled version of a and b
newB1 = repmat(newB1',1,numel(a));
newB2 = repmat(newB2',1,numel(a));
newA = repmat(a,numel(b)-1,1);

%find linear indices that meet required conditions
LinearInd = find(newA<newB2 & newA>newB1);
%convert linear indices to subscripts
[i,newInd] = ind2sub(size(newA),LinearInd);
% display indices that correspond to ind
newInd
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort but this code is an order of magnitude slower than the for loop one...